# How to copy TypedArray into another TypedArray?

Tags: javascript, performance, typedarray

C# has a high performance array copying function to copy arrays *in place*:

```
Array.Copy(source, destination, length)
```

It's faster than doing it manually ie.:

```
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
    destination[i] = source[i];
```

I am looking for an equivalent high performance copy function to copy arrays *in place*, for `Int32Array` and `Float32Array` in JavaScript and can find no such function:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray

The closest is `copyWithin` which only does a copy internally within an array.

Is there a built in high performance copy function for `TypedArray`s *in place*?

Plan B, is there a built in high performance clone function instead? (EDIT: looks like `slice()` is the answer to that)

Comment: u can use Array.join()

Comment: @علاء الدين, `Array.join`? that does not even return an array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copying array by value in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486085/copying-array-by-value-in-javascript)

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I disagree that this question is a duplicate. This question asks first and foremost how to copy values into an *existing array*, while that question asks how to *create a new array*. (This question tolerates the creation of a new array only as a last resort.) In this case, the answer appears to be `.set`; in that case the answer is `.slice`. Nevertheless, I think that other question is a helpful pointer.

Comment: Can we get a sample data set to compare the answers in a performance test?

Comment: Agree this is not a duplicate as setting "in place" is part of the question. Looks like ".set()" is the answer.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You're looking for [`.set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/set) which allows you to set the values of an array using an input array (or TypedArray), optionally starting at some offset on the destination array:

```
destination.set(source);
destination.set(source, offset);
```

Or, to set a limited amount of the input array:

```
destination.set(source.slice(limit), offset);
```

If you instead want to create a new TypedArray, you can simply use `.slice`:

```
source.slice();
```

Comment: BTW If you're looking for efficiency you might use `source.subarray(limit)` instead of `slice` so only a new view is created and the same underlying data store is used (no intermediate data copy required).

Comment: It is really unfortunate that `TypesArray.set()` does not accept an optional third parameter to limit the number of entries to be copied. So currently creating an intermediate view using `source.subarray(limit)` seems to be the way to go.

Answer (score 9):

You can clone an array using `slice(0);`.

```
var clone = myArray.slice(0);
```

And you can make it a native method:

```
Array.prototype.clone = function() {
    return this.slice(0);
};
```

Performance [link](http://jsperf.com/loop-vs-slice-copy/3) comparing to loop

Comment: [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/slice)  is the way to go. If that ain't high performance enough, then the downvoter should downvote JavaScript, not the messenger.

Comment: You don't need to `0`. See the duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7486085/215552

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan, actually the 0 runs faster, and this was a performance question.

Comment: Thanks, actually for good reasons my preference is to copy into an existing array "in place" to minimize memory volatility and having to update references. Hence slice() is undesirable. The performance link seems to be for JS arrays, not TypedArrays.

Comment: Yeah I intended to set up a jsperf for a TypedArray but got distracted. Glad someone pointed you in the right direction.

Comment: Please do not extend the native array. It is much much slower than just doing `.slice(0)`.

Answer (score 6):

clone to an exist typedarray:

```
destination.set(source);
destination.set(source, offset);
```

clone to a new typedarray example: (It's fastest!)

```
var source = new Uint8Array([1,2,3]);
var cloned = new Uint8Array(source);
```

Comment: About using the constructor, good tip. Though I'd like to point out that if the cloned array already exists (ex you are using a double-buffer setup) then `.set` is (by my measurement) 20 times faster (1.5 ms self time vs 29.8 ms self time), as it does not need to allocate memory. (My test involved a pair of Uint32Arrays each with 10,000 items, containing semi-random data in a real-world use-case)